# Flickering occurs when mouse moves over the object- Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am drawing some objects (eg Rectangle) on a canvas. It has a background image as well.

But When I am drawing the rectangle using the mouse events, the screen flickers a lot.
How can I stop the flickering on mouse move/mouse down as I am changing the positrion of object so its repainting the canvas again and again.
Can we render it for sometime or any other solution to it ?

I have heard there is some function as "Redraw = false"in java and C# but my code is in JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/G6tLn/7/`function myMove(e) {
        if (isDrag) {
            getMouse(e);

```
        mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
        mySel.y = my - offsety;

        // something is changing position so we better invalidate the canvas!
        invalidate();
    } else if (isResizeDrag) {
        // time ro resize!
        var oldx = mySel.x;
        var oldy = mySel.y;

        // 0  1  2
        // 3     4
        // 5  6  7
        switch (expectResize) {
            case 0:
                mySel.x = mx;
                mySel.y = my;
                mySel.w += oldx - mx;
                mySel.h += oldy - my;
                break;
            case 1:
                mySel.y = my;
                mySel.h += oldy - my;
                break;
            case 2:
                mySel.y = my;
                mySel.w = mx - oldx;
                mySel.h += oldy - my;
                break;
            case 3:
                mySel.x = mx;
                mySel.w += oldx - mx;
                break;
            case 4:
                mySel.w = mx - oldx;
                break;
            case 5:
                mySel.x = mx;
                mySel.w += oldx - mx;
                mySel.h = my - oldy;
                break;
            case 6:
                mySel.h = my - oldy;
                break;
            case 7:
                mySel.w = mx - oldx;
                mySel.h = my - oldy;
                break;
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    getMouse(e);
    // if there's a selection see if we grabbed one of the selection handles
    if (mySel !== null && !isResizeDrag) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            // 0  1  2
            // 3     4
            // 5  6  7

            var cur = selectionHandles[i];

            // we dont need to use the ghost context because
            // selection handles will always be rectangles
            if (mx >= cur.x && mx <= cur.x + mySelBoxSize &&
                    my >= cur.y && my <= cur.y + mySelBoxSize) {
                // we found one!
                expectResize = i;
                invalidate();

                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        this.style.cursor = 'nw-resize';
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        this.style.cursor = 'n-resize';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        this.style.cursor = 'ne-resize';
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        this.style.cursor = 'w-resize';
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        this.style.cursor = 'e-resize';
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        this.style.cursor = 'sw-resize';
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        this.style.cursor = 's-resize';
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        this.style.cursor = 'se-resize';
                        break;
                }
                return;
            }

        }
        // not over a selection box, return to normal
        isResizeDrag = false;
        expectResize = -1;
        this.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }

}
```

`

Comment: Edited the question. Please help in stopping the flickering due to mouse move

Comment: I tried your fiddle and it's not flickering. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: In the fiddle its not flickering but when I add this to my application . It flickers when I change the position of rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

500+ lines...that's a lot to diagnose!

Some thoughts after a quick scan of that code:

1. When a rectangle is being created or resized, **use a separate editing canvas that's overlaid on top of the results canvas**.  That way the only thing being redrawn is the rect that you're working on--not every previous rect also.  When the creation/resizing is complete then draw the overlay canvas to the display canvas.
2. **Use requestAnimationFrame** instead of setInterval to do timed redraws.  R.A.F synchronizes its redraws with the refresh cycle of the display for better performance.
3. **Don't use separate resizers.**  Managing separate resizers *takes a lot of compute time*.  Instead do what o/s do and let the user drag-resize the border of the shape.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider setting a breakpoint and taking a closer look what actually happens in your code.

Flickering means clearing the canvas clearing and redrawing do not happen synchronously. There could be many reasons how this could be happening.

One would be that you clear your canvas or resize it as part of an event handler, leaving you with a blank canvas until your drawloop happens and redraws everything.

If it's very important that something gets updated synchronously to an event, like a mouse move or scroll, redraw your canvas as part of the event handler.

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
    doSomething();
    redrawOnce();
},false);
```

But be careful not to accidently start multiple loops. Make sure your draw function doesn't call itself. Like in this example:

```
function redrawOnce(){
   //That's not how to redraw once
   requestAnimationFrame(redrawOnce);
}
```

Instead separate your draw from your loop

```
function loop(){
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    redrawOnce();
}
```

Since redrawing the entire canvas to update a change in a small part of it is decadent you may also consider only redrawing the part that changed by the event if that's an option for what you are doing.